# Date Convert in to special Format in iphone

Tags: nsdateformatter, date-conversion

I get a date's parsed data in the form like as `"2014-09-20 09:59:30"` and I want to convert them into 20 SEP 2014. and print it into label.
How can I convert them and print it into the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got then Answer of my this Question so i poet here i got the Date in format like as "2014-09-20 09:59:30" From JSON Data and i want to show this Date in the Format like as 20 SEP 2014 then i got a Code for this is
And if we want to convert it in to upper case then just write label.text string to uppercaseString.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *date=[dict valueForKey:@"post_date"];
NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM YYYY"];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
cell.dateLabel.text=[dateFormatted uppercaseString];
```